# CSS, HTML: Internet Explorer 7 doesn’t move the term to the next line

Tags: html, css

how can I fix this problem on Internet Explorer 7:

If I resize the browser window you'll see that the letters of the last tag on the right (in the header) are displayed in vertical one above each other.

This happen only in IE, and not in other browser (you can better see the bug by visiting the website: http://www.sanstitre.ch/drupal/portfolio

How can I ask IE 7 to consider the word as block, and move it to next line instead of listing the letters in vertical ?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using:

```
.views-exposed-widgets
{
    white-space: nowrap
}
```

In your CSS.

Of course, IE 7 isn't a great browser, so if you're having trouble, try also:

```
<span style=”white-space: nowrap”> your content here </span>
```

That might do the trick.